# Problems using sqlAlchemy to execute SQL queries on my database

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am working on a project to work on a website that connects to a mysql server using flask and sqlAlchemy (Hosted on AWS RDS) and I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHABtemkS-c&t=5s) but when I try to do (/api/bar) I get this error. When I just do my localhost:8080 it shows "Hello World" perfectly fine.

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

config.py
database_url = "mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost:3306/barbeerdrinker"

Here is my **__init__**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
import json

from barbeerdrinker import database

#Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"

@app.route("/api/bar", methods=["GET"])
def get_bars():
    return jsonify(database.get_bars())

@app.route("/api/bar/<name>", methods=["GETS"])
def find_bar(name):
    try:
        if name is None:
            raise ValueError("Bar is not specified")
        bar = database.find_bar(name)
        if bar is None:
            return make_response("No bar found within given name", 404)
        return jsonify(bar)
    except ValueError as e:
        return make_response(str(e), 400)
    except Exception as e:
        return make_response(str(e), 500) 

@app.route("/api/beers_cheaper_than", methods=["POST"])
def find_beers_cheaper_than():
    body = json.loads(request.data)
    max_price = body['maxPrice']
    return jsonify(database.filter_beers(max_price))
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import sql

from barbeerdrinker import config

engine = create_engine(config.database_url)

def get_bars():
    with engine.connect() as con:
        rs = con.execute("SELECT name, address, city, opening, closing, phoneNum FROM bars")
        return [dict(row) for row in rs]

def find_bar(name):
    with engine.connect() as con:
        query = sql.text("SELECT * FROM bars WHERE name = :name;")
        rs = con.execute(query, name=name)
        result = rs.first()
        if result is None:
            return None
        return dict(result)

def filter_beers(max_price):
    with engine.connect() as con:
        query = sql.text("SELECT * FROM sells WHERE price < : max_price;")
        rs = con.execute(query, max_price=max_price)
        results = [dict(row) for row in rs]
        for r in results:
            r['price'] = float(r['price'])
        return results
```

**Edit: So it seems like the problem is not an issue with my code but a Windows error. One solution I tried to do was to open up the required ports through my firewall to no avail.

Comment: None of this code is relevant. Sounds like Windows is configured to reject requests on that port.

Comment: I tried to open up those ports in my firewall to no avail

Comment: Is this all local or is the DB hosted?

Comment: DB is hosted on an AWS RDS server

Comment: Ahaha, I just spotted `barbeerdrinker`. I don't know enough in this area to help you, sorry, but I'm 99.99% sure it's nothing to do with python, it's a Windows issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, turns out the issue is not a windows issue. The problem is within my `config.py`:

Instead of:
`database_url = "mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost:3306/barbeerdrinker"`

It should be:
`database_url = "mysql+pymysql://username:password@**AWSENDPOINT/HOSTNAME**:3306/barbeerdrinker"`